# How to align svg icon inside a button in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I am trying to put the svg icon inside the faq button.
Can i use only flex box to align the icon inside the button?

This is my output:
[image: This is my output:]

And this what i want to achieve:
[image: And this what i want to achieve]

This is some of my css:

```
.section-custom{
margin: 50px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;  /*cross axis for column  */
}

  
.div-faq{
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;

}

 
.div-faq-list-item{
display: flex;
align-items: center;  /*cross axis for row   */
}

.faq-btn{
background-color: #333;
font-size: 25px;
border: 0;
width: 800px;
padding: 22px;
margin: 4px;
text-align: left;
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<section class="section-custom">
            <h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>

            <ul class="div-faq">
                <li class="div-faq-list-item">
                    <button class="faq-btn">What is Netflix?
                     </button>
                     <svg style="height: 50px; width: 50px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#333333"></rect> 
                        <path d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" fill="#ffffff"></path>
                     </svg>
                </li>
                <li class="div-faq-list-item"><button class="faq-btn">How much does Netflix cost?</button>
                    
                </li>
                <li class="div-faq-list-item"><button class="faq-btn">Where can I watch?</button></li>
                <li><button class="faq-btn">How do i cancel?</button></li>
                <li><button class="faq-btn">What can I watch on Netflix?</button></li>
                <li><button class="faq-btn">is Netflix good for kids?</button></li>

            </ul>

        </section>
```

Comment: Pls post the appropriate HTML code for them. It will help us understand the structure of your HTML elements and we will be able to help you much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Remove the fill property from the SVG icon and also make the button and SVG background transparent.
> In-display flex you can achieve this result by justify-content:space-between;

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  gap:0.6rem;
  background-color:black;
  padding:1rem;
}
ul li{
  display:flex;
  padding:1rem;
  background-color:#2e2e2e;
  color:white;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center
  
}
li svg{
  fill:transparent;
}
button{
  font-size:1.6rem;
  background-color:transparent;
  color:white;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="div-faq">
    <li class="div-faq-list-item">
      <button class="faq-btn">What is Netflix?</button>
       <svg style="height: 50px; width: 50px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><rect width="100%" height="100%" ></rect> 
       <path d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" fill="#ffffff"></path>
       </svg>
     </li>
     <li class="div-faq-list-item">
      <button>How much does Netflix cost?</button>
      <svg style="height: 50px; width: 50px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><rect width="100%" height="100%" ></rect> 
      <path d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" fill="#ffffff"></path>
      </svg>
    </li>



 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main{
     margin: 50px;
}
 .button-box{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     background-color: #aaa;
     height: 50px;
     line-height: 50px;
}
 .title{
     padding: 0px 20px;
}
 .icon{
     align-self: center;
     background-color: #bbb;
     width: 40px;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
}
 .icon img{
     width: 24px;
     height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
   <div class="button-box">
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="icon"><img src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/1.2.3/src/icon-ios7-plus.svg" /></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add the svg icon to the button, you must include it inside the tags as shown:

```
<button class="faq-btn">
    What is Netflix?
    <svg style="height: 50px; width: 50px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#333333"></rect> 
        <path d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" fill="#ffffff"></path>
    </svg>
</button>
```

In the css styling, make use of flexbox to help position elements. In your case, flexbox should be applied to the button class to allow for the use of space-between and center item alignment. The css styling should look like this:

```
.faq-btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 0;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 22px;
  margin: 4px;
  text-align: left;
}
```